# pywifi python macos

Tags: python

Подскажите как запустить библиотеку pywifi на macos. Получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrey/PycharmProjects/open_wlan/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pywifi
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке вы в принципе не установили `pywifi`. Как устанавливали и как запускаете?

Comment: все поставил! Все установил, но оно не хочет дружить с маком

Comment: Раз вы решили проблему, вы можете оставить [ответ на свой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), что бы помочь другим с похожей проблемой. Или [удалить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) вопрос, если считаете необходимым.

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки полностью

Comment: Проблема в том, что данная библиотека просто не работает на macos. И не понятно, можно ли ее запустить на ней. Мне вообще нужно сделать простое действие, программно подключится к wifi. Половина библиотек которые просмотрел, не работают на маке.